# How to set UILabel on UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've done this several dozen times with custom and standard `UITableView` cells. All my outlets are connected. The `UILabel` is a subview of my `UICollectionViewCell` in IB. My `UICollectionViewCell` object inherits the proper class in identity inspector.

How do I set `UILabel` on `UICollectionViewCell`?

#### MyCell.m

```
-(void)setCellName:(NSString *)cellName {
    self.cellLabel.text = cellName;
}
```

#### ViewController.m

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ADMCell *cell = 
     (ADMCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ADMCell" 
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setCellName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Output of cell.debugDescription:

```
2013-05-15 22:05:40.191 ProductName[857:c07] cell.debugDescription: 
   <ADMCell: 0xb35c890; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; 
   frame = (245 266; 70 80); layer = <CALayer: 0xb35c780>>`
```

Comment: Did you set the cell in IB to have the right identifier "ADMCell" so it gets dequeued properly?

Comment: can you NSLog("%@",cell.debugDescription) after you assigned the title ? Just in case cell is nil... And confirm that @"AMDCell" is the only one registered.

Comment: So what problem are you having? Is `self.cellLabel` nil? Is cell the wrong type of cell? We don't know what's wrong if you don't tell us.

Comment: Dan Fairaizl, the identifier is set as ADMCell. Alex, i've included the output above. Sorry for the lack of details. @Caleb `setCellName:` never sets the label on the cell. [Check out this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZaKQ5tX.png).

Comment: mmmm... ok.. if you set a break point in - cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, and you inspect cell.cellLabel, does it hold the expected text ? And the text label, just in case, there is nothing in the forefront that obfuscate the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it works for me.

cell.h file

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

     @interface CelebretiesCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
     {
         UIImageView *imgHairPhoto;
     }
     @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
     @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgHairPhoto;
```

cell.m file

```
     @synthesize titleLabel,imgHairPhoto;

     - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {
         self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
         if (self) {

             // Initialization code
             NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CelebretiesCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

             if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
                 return nil;
             }

             if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
                 return nil;
             }

             self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];

         }
         return self;
     }
     @end
```

// Take collectionviewCell in xib and make outlet on CollectionViewXib.

[image]

/////////////////////////////////////

now use of collection view

```
        viewdidload method

          [self.YourCollectionViewObj registerClass:[CelebretiesCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"celebretiesCollectionViewCell"];


       //Datasource and delegate method
       - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                   return [arrFavorites count];///Your array count
       }
       - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
           return 1;
       }
       - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celebretiesCollectionViewCell";
           CelebretiesCollectionViewCell *cell;
           cell = (CelebretiesCollectionViewCell *)[YourCollectionViewObj dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
             cell.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 120);// set frame as per xib

             cell.imgHairPhoto.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strPath]];
               cell.titleLabel.text = shrObj.strCelebrityName;
               return cell;
       }

       - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:        (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
           return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, 0, 0, 0); //set as per your requirements.
       }
```

Comment: Traveling. I'll try this when I get some time. I take it this method should still work as I'm using storyboards. My cell on the storyboard should simply inherit from the class, eg, CelebretiesCollectionViewCell, or ADMCell. Correct?

Comment: yes, use your cell name instead of CelebretiesCollectionViewCell

Comment: This did the trick. Funny how similar this is to a custom UITableViewCell I should have tried this first. Thank you, sir!