# How do I change the value of a UILabel inside of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a collection view and inside the collection view cell I've placed a UILabel.

These are the values I want to assign to the label as each cell that will appear in the view is created:

```
let fibonacciSeries = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8", "13", "21", "34", "55", "89", "144", "∞", "☯"]

let myDeck = Card().createDeck(fibonacciSeries)

struct Card {

    var name: String

    func createDeck(deckType: [String]) -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()
        for name in deckType {
            deck.append(Card(name: name))
            }
            return deck
        }
    }
```

I get a 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIView' error in this function where I'm trying to assign the values to the label:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardCell

    let value = myDeck[indexPath.row]
    cell.addSubview(value.name) <----- error here
    return cell
}
```

I think I actually understand what it's telling me; the cell.addSubview wants to be given a UIView but I'm giving it value.name (a string). I've found some posts here that might answer the question but they're in Objective-C which I don't know the first thing about. For example: [How to set UILabel on UICollectionViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575274/how-to-set-uilabel-on-uicollectionviewcell)

I also tried this:

```
...

    let value = myDeck[indexPath.row].name <--- this didn't work
    cell.addSubview(value)
    return cell
}
```

Any help for this beginner is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cell.addSubview(value), value here should be an UIView, but your value is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardCell
  var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
  label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
  label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
  label.text = myDeck[indexPath.row].name as! String 
  cell.addSubview(label) 
    return cell
}
```