# Load multiple images from web directory in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I require a simple but potentially complex solution that I can't seem to find code that translates from Android for my iOS version APP.

I simply need a imageview grid such as shown here from a single web directory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIX4SnBLaZg

I have a working version on Android but can't seem to figure it out on Objective C.

My working version uses JSON to find each file in the directory and associated text, then simply adds each entry to the grid. The iOS version doesn't need to be as complicated if anyone has any examples?

Would anyone have any examples/snippets/APIs of implementing something like this into iOS?

Or even a simplified version such as only images from a directory. Simply have the thread read an entire folder from URL, file by file, and populate it in imageview's. Then once a user clicks on an image, simply view it full screen?

Comment: Please have a  look at this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: This is the problem I was having, sure this will work but I need to predefine file names in this one. I need the code to scan through an entire folder and populate whatever is in it to the app?

Comment: Are u telling that u will have image in project itself.

Comment: Post you requirement clearly , are you want scan folders inside the project or throughout the iOS device?

Comment: Hi there. It looks like a helpful individual prepared a zip file containing code as part of their answer. How did you get on with that? Are you able to accept the answer?

Comment: Downvoted with regrets (see above).

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can use collection view . Please follow the below tutorial

[uicollectionview-basic-tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

And to get images of `jpg` stored in bundle under folder named `Images`

```
NSArray *imagesOfjpgType = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg"
                                                                    inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

To customize the cell to your design Please use the below code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579595/1142743

Also Please find sample from above tutorial which has a label below the image

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uymyrwtx2yn9fs/RecipePhoto.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to work well! Is there anyway I can associate a text underneth each item in the collection view? Or perhaps store the text in a JSON file?

Comment: Give me sometime i will give you sample . with code of that tutorial itself